# Passed function is not well-serializable! in Playwright

Tags: python, playwright-python

I try to remove an input readonly attribute with playwright-python by using following code:

```py
await page.frames[1].evalOnSelector("input[name=cost_month]", "el => el.removeAttribute('readonly'))")
```

But I always get the `"passed function is not well-serializable!"` error.
Does anyone can help me?

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis there.

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: The last argument should be "el => el.removeAttribute('readonly')"

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice there was a redundant parenthesis. Thanks. @hardkoded